# posting image to local server from android client

Tags: android

**trying to determine**::server is running fine, android is not sending image to server

**MainActivity.java**

```
    public void postImageData() throws IOException
    {
        Drawable myDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.image);
        Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)myDrawable).getBitmap();
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost("http://127.0.0.1/Details/");
        MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);

        try{
            ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 75, bos);
            byte[] data = bos.toByteArray();
            ByteArrayBody bab = new ByteArrayBody(data, "forest.jpg");
            reqEntity.addPart("key", bab);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            //Log.v("Exception in Image", ""+e);
            reqEntity.addPart("key", new StringBody(""));
        }
        postRequest.setEntity(reqEntity);       
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(postRequest);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));
        String sResponse;
        StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
        while ((sResponse = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            s = s.append(sResponse);
        }
    }
```

---

**Any help to resolve this** ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"catch(Exception e){
            //Log.v("Exception in Image", ""+e);
            reqEntity.addPart("key", new StringBody(""));
        }"?
I'd suggest u to print the stackTrace.. Possibly, an exception is occuring in the associated try block..